# Elasticsearch + Log4j2 + Spring shutdown problems

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We got a application without web context with the following dependencies:

```
spring-boot-starter
spring-boot-starter-log4j2
spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch
```

With Elasticsearch 2.2 at shutdown there is always this exception:

```
ERROR Unable to register shutdown hook because JVM is shutting down. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add new shutdown hook as this is not started. Current state: STOPPED
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.addShutdownCallback(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:113)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.addShutdownCallback(Log4jContextFactory.java:273)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setUpShutdownHook(LoggerContext.java:256)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:216)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:145)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:182)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:103)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.slf4j.Slf4jESLoggerFactory.newInstance(Slf4jESLoggerFactory.java:39)
at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLoggerFactory.getLogger(ESLoggerFactory.java:62)
at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Loggers.java:146)
at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Loggers.java:109)
at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Loggers.java:75)
at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractComponent.<init>(AbstractComponent.java:38)
at org.elasticsearch.cache.recycler.PageCacheRecycler.<init>(PageCacheRecycler.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:50)
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:86)
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl$5$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:828)
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:880)
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl$5.get(InjectorImpl.java:823)
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:867)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.close(TransportClient.java:281)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:364)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:982)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1008)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:984)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:903)
```

It seems to be a log4j problem. Any way to fix or suppress this? Does it even have any effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1222. It will be fixed in the 2.6 release. The cause is that something is trying to log after log4j has already shut down.